# Lemma 6.2.1 in Qing Liu

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The Lemma states:

> Let $A$ be a finitely generated algebra over a field $k$. Let $x \in \operatorname{Spec} A$
>   be a rational point corresponding to a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$. Then the canonical
>   homomorphism
>   $$\delta : \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 → \Omega^1_{A/k} \otimes_A k(x)$$
>   is an isomorphism.

The proof begins with:

> The cokernel of $\delta$ is $\Omega^1_{k(x)/k} = 0$.

Now by Lemma 6.1.13 we know that $\Omega^1_{L/K} = 0$ if and only if $L/K$ is separable.

I don't see why $k(x)/k$ is separable.

---

There is a similar statement in Hartshorne Proposition II.8.7, but it assumes $A$ to be a local ring that contains a field $k$ isomorphic to its residue field. In this case we only have to check $\Omega^1_{k/k} = 0$, which is trivial.

**Edit:** The point $x$ is assumed to be rational, so $k(x) = k$.

Comment: Is the field $k$ of characteristic $0$?

Comment: Isn't rational point means that $k(x)= k$ or some other assumption is needed?

Comment: @ChirantanChowdhury Yes, you are right. I am fascinated how I was able to miss that ...

Comment: I also made it as an answer in others to see if they also had the same doubts. I hope it is ok with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x$ is a rational point so $k(x) = k$ .Isn't it, if i am right?